# Python Pygments color error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygments

I've been trying to make a simple text pad with syntax highlighting for python. but the problem is when i open quote a string ad pt the closing quote, the text are the quotes doesn't change back, here's how it looks:

[image: Heading]

here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *       # All from Tkinter

# =============================================================================
class vwin():
    def __init__(self,args,master=None):
        if type(args[3]) == type(self):
            self.window = Toplevel(args[3].window)
        elif args[3].lower() == 'tk':
            self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title(args[0])
        self.window.geometry(args[1])
        self.window.state(args[2])

    def mainloop():
        self.window.mainloop()

class customtext:
    def __init__(self,master):
        import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolltxt
        self.textarea = scrolltxt.ScrolledText(master)
        self.textarea.configure(bg = "#555555",
                           insertbackground = "#dddddd",
                           font = "Courier 14 bold",
                           tabs = 40,
                           foreground="#dddddd")
        self.textarea.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

        # TAGS ----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.textarea.tag_configure("Token.Comment",
                                    foreground="#00ff00")
        self.textarea.tag_configure("Token.Literal.String",
                                    foreground="#ff99cc")
        self.textarea.tag_configure("Token.Keyword",
                                    foreground="#aaaa00")
        self.textarea.tag_configure("Token.Name.Function",
                                    foreground="#ffff00")


    def highlight(self,event=None):
        # Imports PythonLex from Pygments -----
        from pygments import lex
        from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
        # Content Search ------------------------------------------------------
        self.textarea.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
        data = self.textarea.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
            self.textarea.mark_set("range_end",
                                   "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
            self.textarea.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
            self.textarea.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

    def stat_title(self,event=None):
        ind = self.textarea.index(INSERT)
        root.window.title('VenomPad Mini' + "[Index:" + str(ind) + "]")

    def select_all(self,event):
        self.textarea.tag_add(SEL, "1.0", END)
        self.textarea.mark_set(INSERT, "1.0")
        self.textarea.see(INSERT)
# =============================================================================



# :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
root = vwin(['VenomPad Mini','640x480-25-25','normal','Tk'])       

text = customtext(root.window)
root.window.bind("<Key>", text.highlight)
root.window.bind("<KeyRelease>", text.stat_title)
root.window.bind("<Control-Key-a>", text.select_all)

root.window.mainloop()
# :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 3):

Tagging a range inside another range, doesn't shorten the range.

The simplest thing I could think of would be to remove the existing tags before adding the tags:

```
def highlight(self,event=None):
    ...
    data = self.textarea.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    # Remove the existing tags from textarea
    for tag in self.textarea.tag_names():
        self.textarea.tag_remove(tag, "1.0", "end")

    for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
        self.textarea.mark_set("range_end",
                               "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
        self.textarea.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
        self.textarea.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")
    ...
```